# Create a Empty Wish-list Button in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

i want to create a empty wishlist button in wishlist page, so that when user click the button all the items from the wishlist are removed. how can i do that please help.

Comment: you want to remove wishlist items

Comment: yes, i want to remove all items at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of adding button in wishlist, change button as per your need

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <reference name="customer.wishlist.buttons">
        <block type=“wedding/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.gifts" template=“wedding/button/gifts.phtml" />
    </reference>
</wishlist_index_index>
```

You need to add separate controller action on this button click

> Code of empty Wishlist

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
 $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();

$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
    foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: can you give me the location for this controller

Comment: @abhishek you need to make controller in your custom module path would be some thing like app/code/local/Packagename/Yourmodulename/ in controller folder if you still don't get it please check any tutorial how to add controller in custom module it is very basic.  After adding controller you have to hit controller action through url either by setting form action or  button on click. If my answer is helpful please mark it correct. Keep coding :) thanks